# Specify More "case" in switch parameters

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
$ErrorType = null;
switch ($ErrNo) {
    case 256, 1:
        $ErrorType = "Error";
        break;
    case 512, 2:
        $ErrorType = "Warning";
        break;
    case 1024, 8:
        $ErrorType = "Notice";
        break;
    case 2048:
        $ErrorType = "Strict Warning";
        break;
    case 8192:
        $ErrorType = "Depreciated";
        break;
}
```

But the problem is, I'm going from the pre-defined constants for an error handling software solution.. I cannot specify more than one "case" for the dedicated error categories, example:

```
switch ($ErrNo){
 case 1:
     $ErrorType = "Error";
     break;
 case 256:
     $ErrorType = "Error";
}
```

That's a repeat of code.. Whereas with a solution like my first example, it would be beneficial as two integers fall under the same category.. Instead, i'm returned with the following:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in Action_Error.php on line
>   37

Answer (score 5):

Specify multiple cases like this

```
switch ($ErrNo){
    case 256:
    case 1:
        $ErrorType = "Error";
        break;
// ...
```

ref: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Answer (score 1):

Specify duplicate cases without using `break` between them. Example:

```
switch ($ErrNo) {
    case 256:
    case 1:
        $ErrorType = "Error";
        break;    

    case 512:
    case 2:
        $ErrorType = "Warning";
        break;    

    /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do this is:

```
switch ($ErrNo){
    case 1:
    case 256:
        $ErrorType = "Error";
        break;
    case 512:
    case 2:
        $ErrorType = "Error";
        break;
}
```